# How to call an item in an array using a variable in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

I'm trying to write a function that cycles through an integer array looking for zeros. It looks like this:

```
def fullIntArray(arr:Array[Int]): Boolean = {

  var counter = 0;
  for(a <- 1 to arr.length by 1){
    if(arr(a) != 0){
      counter += 1;
    }
  }

  if(counter == arr.length){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

I'm getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` from

```
arr(a)
```

Can anyone explain why, or what I should do instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 4):

You're getting the exception because the index of the first element in an `Array` is zero, not one. The following works (the `by 1` is fine but unnecessary):

```
for (a <- 0 to arr.length - 1 by 1) {
  if (arr(a) != 0) {
    counter += 1
  }
}
```

And so does the following, as @puhlen suggested:

```
for (a <- 0 until arr.length) {
  ...
}
```

However, a better way to implement your function is:

```
def fullIntArray(arr: Array[Int]): Boolean = arr.forall(_ != 0)
```

Comment: you can also use `0 until arr.length` instead of `0 to arr.length - 1` to create you range

Comment: @puhlen: Updated.